# The random variable $log(\frac{X}{x_0})$ has an exponential distribution with parameter $\alpha$

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, exponential-distribution, pareto-distribution

It is said that a random variable $X$ has a Pareto distribution with parameters $x_0$ and $\alpha$ for $(x_0 > 0)$ and $(\alpha > 0)$ if $X$ has a continuous distribution for which the p.d.f. $f(x|x_0, \alpha)$ is as follows:

$$f(x|x_0, \alpha) = \frac{\alpha x_0^\alpha}{x^{\alpha +1}},\quad x\ge x_0, x_0>0, \alpha>0.$$

Show that if $X$ has this Pareto distribution, the random variable $\log(X/x_0)$ has an exponential distribution with parameter $\alpha$.

I took the approach of $Y = \log(X/x_0)$ and re-arranged for $X$ to get $X = x_0\exp(Y)$.

though I'm unsure of how to proceed from here. Furthermore, what actually explains that a relations exists between the Pareto distribution and an exponential distribution; for example, why is $\log(X/x_0)$ mentioned?

My further approach:

$x_0\exp(y)dy = dx$

then $$g(y) = f(x_0\exp(y)|x_0, \alpha) = \frac{\alpha x_0^{\alpha}}{(x_0\exp(y))^{\alpha+1}}x_0\exp(y)=\frac{\alpha}{\exp(y)^{\alpha}}=\alpha\exp(y)^{-\alpha}$$

Comment: Hint: start with $P(Y \leq y)$. As for why $\log$s, one way to get heavy tailed distributions is to take the exponential of a not-heavy tailed distribution, so this places the Pareto in company with the lognormal distribution as being of this form

Comment: Hint: the question is precisely asking to show that the transform variable $\log(X/x_0)$ is distributed as an exponential variable when $X$ is distributed as a Pareto variable.

Comment: @Xi'an I have updated my approach please let me know if I went down the right place

Comment: You will find this question easier to answer by considering the CDF, as suggested by @jld in the initial hint.

Comment: While it's easier to use the cdf, you can take your calculation a step further by considering properties of powers ($\exp(y) = e^y$)

Comment: Your final equation is a solution to the question using the change of variable approach, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Let $X\sim Pareto(x_0,\alpha)$, then the PDF is as you wrote and the CDF is
$$P(X\le k)=1-\left(\frac{x_0}{k}\right)^{\alpha}.$$

Now denote $Y=log\left(\frac{X}{x_0}\right)$, it only takes 5 transitions from $P(Y\le y)$ in order to show $Y\sim exp(\alpha)$:

$$P(Y\le y)=P\left( log\left(\frac{X}{x_0}\right) \le y \right)=P\left( \frac{X}{x_0}\le e^y \right)=P(X \le x_0e^y) \\= 1-\left(\frac{x_0}{x_0e^y}\right)^{\alpha}=1-e^{-\alpha y}$$

Comment: I'm still struggling on how to proceed from the next step as I've have tried a few alternatives already: $\alpha x \left(\frac{x_0}{x_0 e^y} \right)^{\alpha}(1-e^{-ay})$, which leaves me not with the solution

Comment: How did you get this expression?

Comment: I'm in doubt of how to proceed. I've been looking at the solution from the book that provided the question (Probability and statistics, Degroot), he provides this: $g(y) = f(x_0 \exp(y)|x_0, \alpha)x_0 \exp(y)$ Where I presumed we replace $x$ in the Parteo distribution by $x_0 \exp(y)$ as in my first approach towards this.

Comment: The last line of your post up there...   you almost have it at hand. Consider @Glen_b's comment.